# What does a diamond symbol actually mean in pedigree?

Tags: pedigree

Does it mean a person who is neither a male or a female, a homosexual or an individual whose sex is unspecified?

Comment: I find myself voting to close a lot of your questions as unclear or homework - could you start making effort to make questions answerable and effort to answer for yourself

Comment: A simple google search gives tons of answers. Try not to ask too trivial questions just for the sake of posing a question.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 3):

> The figures in this article show symbols commonly used in pedigrees. Squares represent males, circles represent females, and **diamonds depict individuals of unknown or, for reasons of confidentiality, disguised gender**. A double line between parents indicates consanguineous marriages (between blood relatives) (see Figure 3). Filled symbols represent individuals who display a certain trait, such as an inherited disease. Bars next to the symbols represent genetic loci, and different alleles are color-coded. Diseasecausing mutations are shown as stars or crosses. Symbols that are half filled indicate heterozygous individuals, but often this information isn't known.

*From Wikipedia:*

> If the sex of the person is unknown a diamond is used

[image: Pedigree]

*Sources:*

- http://www.biologyreference.com/Oc-Ph/Pedigrees-and-Modes-of-Inheritance.html#ixzz43btGJSuv
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedigree_chart